# How do I try the Ubuntu LiveCD inside Windows?

Tags: windows, live-environment

How can I try Ubuntu in windows directly from iso without burning any disc or using usb drive ?

Comment: you'll need VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To try Ubuntu within Windows, you can run the LiveCD in a "virtual machine" (or a computer within a computer)
- For an optimal experience, your Windows computer should have at least 1.5 GB of RAM.

#### Steps:

1. Download and extract the portable (no installation) version of *VirtualBox*, from the [PenDriveLinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-a-portable-virtualbox-to-run-linux-from-usb/) website -- called [***Tibo's Virtualbox***](http://download.tuxfamily.org/lilicreator/virtualbox/VirtualBox.zip)
2. Start `VirtualBox.exe` and you should see this screen:

   [image]
3. Click on the *Settings* icon on top, and go to *System* in the left sidebar. Set the *Base Memory* to at least 768 MB for regular Ubuntu, or 256 MB for Lubuntu/Xubuntu. If you have at least 3 GB of memory in your computer, you can set this to 1 GB (1024 MB) for optimal performance.

   [image]
4. Now go to *Storage* in the sidebar, and click on the little yellow folder next to *CD/DVD drive*:

   [image]

   This opens the Virtual Media Manager. Click *Add*, and navigate to where you have your Ubuntu LiveCD ISO, and choose it. Finally, click on *Select* to attach the ISO to the "virtual" CD drive:

   [image]
5. Click *OK* to close Settings, and press the big green arrow to start trying Ubuntu!

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use MobaLiveCD Link http://mobalivecd.mobatek.net/en/download.html. 
 Interestingly you don't need any VIRTUAL MACHINE to try just download and try. 
 Steps are as follows (1)Run MobaLiveCD as an administrator. (2) Then click the button "Run the LiveCD". (3) Then select the iso you want to run then Click "Open". (4) Then message will pop up asking to create Hard Disk for your virtual machine. ("I prefer NO") then voila just enjoy "UBUNTU" without affecting your windows installation.

Comment: MobaLiveCD DOES use a virtual machine called [*QEMU*](http://www.qemu.org), which works great in Linux but is usually one of the slowest on Windows. Additionally, MobaLiveCD has caused problems on 64-bit Windows for me in the past. I'd recommend Virtualbox any day.

Comment: I mean to say MobaLiveCD uses virtual machine but the user doesn't requred to install any other virtual machine which need to configure to use. Just think of the ease of trying MabaLiveCD. Least steps to be followed to try and it doesn't required to make any virtual drive like the other virtual machine required to do. You even don't need to install to use and it is very fast to try. Just compare with the other virtual machine. Just think of the novice.